# exit batch processing even if calling program still running

Tags: batch-file, exe

I think it's a simple question, but I don't realize its solution.
I have a batch file that calls an EXE program. It's working fine, but I'd like to close the CMD window without having to click on it.

It's like this:

```
@echo off

[...]

call EXEprogram.exe

[...]

exit
```

I want the CMD window vanishes, even if the EXEprogram is still running, but the control doesn't return to the batch file, to execute the EXIT command. I tested using CALL command calling another batch file that calls EXEprogram and also, don't using the CALL command, but result is the same: CMD window shows that EXEprogram is still running and the control doesn't come back to execute EXIT command.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `start` command instead of `call`:

```
start EXEprogram.exe
```

Type `start /?` for further details.